# AWS Cognito client SDK v3 returns 'byteLength' of undefined when running Admin disable user command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to disable users from my node JS backend using the AWS SDK v3. everything works normally except for the disable/enable user command.

I have tried everything I know but here is my code snippet:

```
const aws_creds = {
  accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
};
const cognitoConfig = {
  region: process.env.REGION,
  credentials: aws_creds,
};

const cognito_v3 = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(cognitoConfig);
```

Then in my route I am running this `try / catch` block

```
try {
    if (status === "enable") {
      const enableUserCommand = new AdminEnableUserCommand(userDetails);
      const enableUserResults = await cognito_v3.send(enableUserCommand);
      return res.status(200).json(enableUserResults);
    }
    const disableUserCommand = new AdminDisableUserCommand(userDetails);
    const disableUserResults = await cognito_v3.send(disableUserCommand);
    return res.status(200).json(disableUserResults);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).json(err);
  }
```

However, the err console log returns this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined
    at Object.fromArrayBuffer (C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\util-buffer-from\dist\cjs\index.js:6:60)
    at castSourceData (C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\hash-node\dist\cjs\index.js:29:31)
    at Hash.update (C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\hash-node\dist\cjs\index.js:12:26)
    at hmac (C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\signature-v4\dist\cjs\credentialDerivation.js:60:10)
    at Object.getSigningKey (C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\signature-v4\dist\cjs\credentialDerivation.js:32:29)
    at SignatureV4.getSigningKey (C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\signature-v4\dist\cjs\SignatureV4.js:139:39)
    at SignatureV4.signRequest (C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\signature-v4\dist\cjs\SignatureV4.js:98:73)
    at async C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-signing\dist\cjs\middleware.js:14:22
    at async StandardRetryStrategy.retry (C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-retry\dist\cjs\defaultStrategy.js:56:46)
    at async C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\middleware-logger\dist\cjs\loggerMiddleware.js:6:22
    at async C:\Users\SER-01\Documents\ctr\simsim\simsim-backend\lambdas\simsim-auth\src\routes\auth.js:232:33 {
  '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 }
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: I had the same error being thrown in node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-buffer-from/dist/cjs/index.js. Make sure secretAccessKey is defined, that fixed the issue for me

Comment: yeah it was, @BillyBaker. All other commands work except for these two. One more thing that was weird is that when I try and import LogoutCommand, it does not import as a constructor?

Comment: If you throw a breakpoint or console log in the constructor of node_modules\@aws-sdk\hash-node\dist\cjs\index.js, the issue may surface. Also check this line: @aws-sdk\signature-v4\dist\cjs\credentialDerivation.js:32:29